# How to force clients to send etag/version using spring data rest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

We are using spring data rest via spring boot (v1.3.3) and have the following entity exposed via the standard REST Repository Exporter:

```
@Document
public class Project {
  @Version
  private Long version;

  @CreatedDate
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

  @CreatedBy
  private String createdBy;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

  @LastModifiedBy
  private String lastModifiedBy;

  private String name;

  //getters and setters omitted

}
```

A POST to /projects or a PUT to /projects/1234 for instance creates a document with etag/version 0. Another PUT to /projects/1234 overwrites the document even if the client does not provide a version/etag. Furthermore A DELETE on /projects/1234 deletes the document even if the client does not provide a version/etag.

How can I configure spring data rest to update and delete the document if and only if the client provides a valid version/etag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API **client** needs to specify a valid ETag on a header in the request, like this:

`If-Match: <value of previous ETag>`

By adding this header to the HTTP request, you convert it into a conditional operation that will only be carried out if it satisfies the condition. There are other conditionals such as `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since`.

It is the responsibility of the **client** to add a conditional header.

From the question I understand that you would like the **server** to disallow any operation that does not provide a valid ETag, but as far as I know Spring Data Rest does not support this.

You can either change your clients to include the proper header (assuming they are under your control), or implement this feature by yourself.

You can take a look at the [Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional) for further info.

Comment: I did a curl request to my entity endpoint and I have no etag in the response. How do I get the value of the previous ETag?

Comment: I have accepted this answer. ESala got my intention. I was looking for an option to disallow all operations which do not origin from a rest request with a valid ETag. Leaving this decision up to the clients is IMHO no choice. Thx ESala for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

> How to force clients to send etag/version using spring data rest?

Simply put: you can't, unless you write the clients.

> How can I configure spring data rest to update and delete the document if and only if the client provides a valid version/etag?

That requires overriding the *PUT/DELETE /projects/1234* handlers provided by Spring Data Rest and deal with ETags on your own.
In order to override the handlers, you need to annotate your controller with [RepositoryRestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) and use RequestMapping [at the method level](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535) to still benefit from the other handlers provided by Spring.
To handle the ETag part, you can dig in the contents of the request headers (search for the If-* headers mentionned by @ESala by adding a HttpServletRequest paramater to your handlers.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class ProjectRepositoryRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Item update(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody Project, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        /* dig into the request headers */
        // for instance
        String header = request.getHeader("If-match"); 
        // or more likely do something with request.getHeaders(...) or request.getHeaderNames(...) to check if the relevant headers are present.
        /* apply your logic on Etags */
        if (null == header) {
            throw new ARelevantException();
        }

        /* go on with the processing of the request if everything is OK */
        Project project = repository.findOne(id);
        /* perform some magic with your entity and your input data */

        project = repository.save(project);

        return project;
    }

}
```

To handle the headers, other options are available, such as using the [RequestHeader](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-requestheader-example/) annotation. You may also give a look at [RequestEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html) to get the request body and header at once (just don't mix a RequestEntity parameter and @RequestBody + @RequestHeader parameters).

Comment: What happens if you do?

> "just don't mix a `RequestEntity` parameter and `@RequestBody` + `@RequestHeader` parameters"

Comment: Nothing actually forbids it. It just seems awkward and pointless since RequestEntity already has the information that you get with RequestBody and RequestHeader.

Comment: This is a repository specific for the entity of type "Project". But is it possible to specify a generic behaviour in order to make possible that any request PATCH or PUT must have the "If-match" parameter in the header? Something like a @WebFilter

Comment: I would let spring data handle the comparison of the etag (assuming its the version). Doing this check on resource level is not thread safe is it?